# How to go this url

Tags: android, url

I got a url from my customer to open another app in the phone for upgrade just like this one:

XXXXXX://launch?url=XXXXX

I don't know how to open this one.
I tried next:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("XXXXXX://launch?url=XXXXX"));
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
startActivity(intent);
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the url should go into the Data field, but no idea about the other fields since that depends on what your customer specified in the <[intent-filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)/>

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("XXX://yyy?zzz"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

did you added below tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file..?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I added the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> and          <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
         </intent-filter>